# A in PSL(2,C) is composed of two inversions

Tags: riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, gromov-hyperbolic-spaces

I wanna show that if $A \in PSL(2,\mathbb{C})$ then $A= i_{c_1} \circ i_{c_2}$ with $i_{c_j}$ inversion of the sphere $c_j$.

I tried to show it so, I can to identify  $A$ with $\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ through the projection action,
then I know that $i_c$ has form $i(x) = a + \frac{r^2}{|x-a|^2}(x-a)$, for a circle $c=C(a,r)$ with $a$ center and $r$ radius, I composed two of it but I have not obtained good news.

Other thing that i know is:

- $A$ has one or two fixed points
- $\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ send generalized circles in circles or lines

I have already shown it

Could you give me some hint?

Thanks

Comment: What is $PSL(2,\mathbb{C})$

Comment: What you are trying to show is simply false: any loxodromic transformation will be a counter-example.